# How do I check for a world in multiple txt files at once?

Tags: database, text, data-analysis, text-editor

I have a huge data set of around 120gbs that contains several txt files of each 2-3 gb+ sizes. I want to look for a string inside all those files at once.

I tried notepad++ find by folder option but it doesn't allow me to open large txt files.

Comment: Consider using `dbeaver` which is a very useful software that let you read large files and query them with SQL for example. You can also search for text in a whole database (which for you is a folder but it shows as a database where each file is a table). When configuring a connection to a folder you have to tell the driver what extension your file have, what is the field separator etc.

Comment: It's a shame you didn't specify what OS but it's probably Windows. On Linux I'd use https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher.